# Custom #! to run file of SQL commands

Tags: mysql, bash

I am looking for a way to have a simple way to execute SQL commands. One attempt is to make a custom #! script but I am not sure how to do this either.

If I do something like:

```
#!/bin/cat -n
select
        col1
from
        table;
```

I get output like

```
      1 #!/bin/cat -n
      2 select
      3     col1
      4 from
      5     table;
```

Which makes me think I could be close.

But when I create a script like runsql.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cat -n

./some_sql.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./some_sql.sh: line 2: `select'
```

This is my attempt at being able to execute sql files. Is there someway people are doing this that I am not doing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
mysql -e "YOUR_SQL_COMMAND"
```

for large command try it (i dont test but need work):

```
sqlCommand=$(cat <<EOF
    This is large
    Sql command
    This is line three.
EOF
)
mysql < $sqlCommand
```

Comment: I was thrilled when I learned of this and that what I was doing before but once my SQL statement got long and included multiple statements for reports the solution was not great. 

Doing mysql < sqlfile.sql works pretty well.

But having the sql file being executable using a custom #! would be great.
`#!/mysql < read this file
-- lots of sql

Select col from table;
select col from table2;`

Comment: Thanks this does help.